# Can't remove version in Jackrabbit

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I'm trying to remove a version from the version history and I'm getting javax.jcr.ReferentialIntegrityException: Unable to remove version. At least once referenced.

When I try to remove all references to the version it seems like there aren't any and still does not allow me to remove the version.
I am sure that this is not the root version and I'm also sure its not the first after the root.

This is my code:

```
    Version ver = manager.checkin(parentNodePath);

    VersionHistory versionHistory = manager.getVersionHistory(parentNodePath);
    PropertyIterator versionReverences = ver.getReferences();
    for (Property verRef = versionReverences.nextProperty(); versionReverences.hasNext();) {
        verRef.remove();
    }
    session.save();
    versionHistory.removeVersion(ver.getName());
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `checkin()` call that creates your version on the first line of your example sets the `jcr:baseVersion` reference from the versionable node to the version you just created. The `verRef.remove()` statement can't remove this reference, as the jcr:baseVersion property is protected.

You need to either remove the content node or use methods like `checkin()` or `update()` to make the `jcr:baseVersion` reference to point to another version before you can remove this version.